# Order Condition Formula in a Shipping Condition

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, conditional, order, shipping

I have digital products that are sold alongside physical products and need a way to set it so that the 'standard shipping' method is not shown as an option if ONLY digital products are in the cart/order. Digital products can be identified by their Tax or Shipping category 'Digital Products'. I can't seem to get the order condition formula in the 'standard shipping' rule to behave how I want it to in order to accomplish this.

Comment: What are you using now for order condition? Weights might also work for you use case to disallow shipping when weight is 0.

Comment: I'm not. I can't figure out how to write the condition. Weights wouldn't work though as some of the physical products don't have weight set given the site has 'flat rate' shipping rather than based on weight.